# Tensorflow-Hub Modules not loading

Tags: python, tensorflow-hub

I am trying to use the universal sentence encoder 4, It works on my desktop at home but I am not home so I am having to re-set everything up. I am using this all in a virtual environment. I have changed nothing in the code. I am on hotel wifi I believe that could be an issue but I also tried it on my mobile hotspot. It typically just freezes as I start the program as if it is trying to initialize the module but nothing happens and it eventually spits out an error.

I have tried using a mobile hotspot to get around this problem and that did not work. I am okay with any kind of work around that doesn't envolve loading it from the internet provided, it would work on an aws instance eventually.

Here is the code I am trying to run:

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
embed =  hub.load(
            'https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4')
print('if this prints it actually loaded')
```

Here is the error:
l/OneDrive/Desktop/pythontest/Testing environ/test.py"
WARNING:absl:Deleting lock file C:\Users\reill\AppData\Local\Temp\tfhub_modules\063d866c06683311b44b4992fd46003be952409c.lock due to inactivity.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\reill\OneDrive\Desktop\pythontest\Testing environ\env\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\resolver.py", line 192, in download_and_uncompress
file_utils.extract_tarfile_to_destination(
File "C:\Users\reill\OneDrive\Desktop\pythontest\Testing environ\env\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\file_utils.py", line 52, in extract_tarfile_to_destination
extract_file(tgz, tarinfo, abs_target_path, log_function=log_function)
File "C:\Users\reill\OneDrive\Desktop\pythontest\Testing environ\env\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\file_utils.py", line 35, in extract_file
buf = src.read(buffer_size)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\reill\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tarfile.py", line 696, in readinto
buf = self.read(len(b))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\reill\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tarfile.py", line 687, in read
raise ReadError("unexpected end of data")
tarfile.ReadError: unexpected end of data

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\reill\OneDrive\Desktop\pythontest\Testing environ\test.py", line 2, in 
embed =  hub.load(
^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\reill\OneDrive\Desktop\pythontest\Testing environ\env\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\module_v2.py", line 93, in load
module_path = resolve(handle)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\reill\OneDrive\Desktop\pythontest\Testing environ\env\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\module_v2.py", line 48, in resolve
return registry.resolver(handle)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\reill\OneDrive\Desktop\pythontest\Testing environ\env\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\registry.py", line 49, in **call**
return impl(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\reill\OneDrive\Desktop\pythontest\Testing environ\env\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\compressed_module_resolver.py", line 67, in **call**
return resolver.atomic_download(handle, download, module_dir,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\reill\OneDrive\Desktop\pythontest\Testing environ\env\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\resolver.py", line 421, in atomic_download
download_fn(handle, tmp_dir)
File "C:\Users\reill\OneDrive\Desktop\pythontest\Testing environ\env\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\compressed_module_resolver.py", line 64, in download
return resolver.DownloadManager(handle).download_and_uncompress(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\reill\OneDrive\Desktop\pythontest\Testing environ\env\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\resolver.py", line 200, in download_and_uncompress
raise IOError("%s does not appear to be a valid module." % self._url)
OSError: https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4 does not appear to be a valid module.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to download the TF Hub universal-sentence-encoder/4 module in Google Colab using Python 3.10 and in conda environment using Python 3.11.
It seems this OSError could be due to network issue as you mentioned. There are some [common issues](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/common_issues#cannot_download_a_module) in TF Hub as below -

1. "**EOF occurred in violation of protocol**" - when the installed python version does not support the TLS requirements of the server hosting the module

2. "**cannot verify tfhub.dev's certificate**" - which is likely to be generated if something on the network is trying to act as the dev gTLD.

3. Failures to write to the cache directory `/tmp/tfhub_modules`

You can try to manually download this module by simulating the protocol of attaching `?tf-hub-format=compressed` to the URL to download a tar compressed file that has to be manually decompressed into a local file

```
# Create a folder for the TF hub module.
!mkdir /tmp/moduleA

#Download the module, and uncompress it to the destination folder. You might want to do this manually.
!curl -L "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4?tf-hub-format=compressed" | tar -zxvC /tmp/moduleA

#Test to make sure it works.
import tensorflow_hub as hub
hub.Module("/tmp/moduleA")
```

or

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
embed =  hub.load(
            'https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4?tf-hub-format=compressed')
print('if this prints it actually loaded')
```

Please have a look at this similar [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/53#issuecomment-405499368) for your reference.